# Order statistics and sample size

Tags: sample-size, ranking, order-statistics, threshold

How do I estimate the odds of the highest value elements of samples from two populations, A and B, exceeding a threshold value, where the same size of A is larger than that of B? Even if A and B have the same population means, the fact that the sample size of A is larger than B implies that I will have more outliers from A than from B. Heckman's sample selection adjustment does not seem to be appropriate.

Comment: Are you sampling with or without replacement? Do you know what the parent distribution of population A is? And B? If so, what are they? And do you know the sample size from each population? Are A and B independent? Then you ask for the odds that the highest value ELEMENTS of samples from the two populations exceed a threshold. Do you seek the P(max[sampleA] > k) and P(max[sampleB] > k), or do you seek P(max[sampleA, sampleB] > k)?  If the former, what difference does the addition of sample  B make (i.e. why are you asking the question)?

Comment: I assume that the original populations from which I sample are large, so replacement is not important. I do not know the parent distribution of population A and B with what I want to test, but I do know the sample sizes. A and B are independent. Yes, I see P(max[sampleA] > k) and P(max[sampleB] > k). Illustration: The 7'6" Chinese basketball player, Yao Ming, was the tallest player in the NBA. However, the population of China is 4 times larger than the US. How much shorter can men in China be for the odds of the tallest player in the NBA to be equally likely to be Chinese or American.

Comment: The highest sample will roughly follow a normal distribution with parameters as described at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic#Large_sample_sizes, using $p=n/(n+1)$, where $n$ is the sample size. So the two probabilities of exceedance will be $z$-scores for those two normal distributions, using different values of $p$ in the two calculations because the sample sizes are different.